# Movie about monsters that come through a portal from the future

Tags: story-identification, movie, time-travel

At first the people who first saw the future were scared of how the world had come to this, so they try to stop the future from happening, but it ends up that the future actually happened because the monsters came through the portal from the future.

So the monsters originated from the same portal from the future; there is no actual start to this. It’s a time paradox, like the movie *Predestination*.

Comment: This reminds me of the Philip K Dick story "Meddler", but as far as I know that story was never made into a movie.

Comment: the movie as I remember does have much to do with government, the people who created the portal to the future saw the outbreak, and in attempt to stop the future that they didn't know yet what caused it, have opened the portal for the monsters to come in, and that in turns is what actually caused the outbreak

Comment: Can you describe the monsters? Was the movie in color or black and white?

Comment: I don't remember the monsters well, I saw the movie at like age 6-9 so memory foggy but I do remember that they were a swarm of them,regular speed, maybe crouched abit. a mixture of zombies and like normal monster type stuff. I don't think the movie was in black in white, I remember color but maybe it could have being.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Time Machine: Rise of the Morlocks* or simply *Morlocks*, a 2011 Sy-Fy movie.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morlock#Time_Machine:_Rise_of_the_Morlocks):

> A 2011 television movie originally named Morlocks (renamed Time Machine: Rise of the Morlocks) produced for Syfy, starring David Hewlett, and Robert Picardo. **The plot sees a time machine open a portal to the future allowing Morlocks to travel back to the present and wreak havoc.** These Morlocks are descended from a patient with terminal cancer whose father used the military time travel project to look for technology in the future as a cure. **One of the first Morlocks to escape through the portal into the present is captured and has its DNA extracted; paradoxically, it is treatment with this DNA that causes the patient to mutate into the first Morlock.**

---

Found with the Google query `science fiction movie "portal * future"` which yielded [the movie's page on the *Time Machine* wikia](https://timemachine.fandom.com/wiki/Morlocks_(Film)). While the query could have applied to both, it happens that I was actually looking for the answer to the very similar question [Movie: in a big seaside city time travel portals open to the apocalyptic future with the fading sun and zombie mutants](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/228568/).